# How does snakemake know files created though a slurm job are incomplete when job is canceled?

Tags: snakemake

for example, if running a job that sumbits to slurm and canceling slurm job via `scancel -u username` and canceling snakemake with `ctrl-c`, on next run snakemake will say:

`The files below seem to be incomplete. If you are sure that certain files are not incomplete, mark them as complete with`

How does it know this? Does it make its own "touch file" internally?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a conclusive answer but maybe this puts you in the right direction: snakemake writes a hidden directory, named `.snakemake`, in the working directory (you need `ls -a` to see it).

Inside `.snakemake` there are various subdirectories and the answer to your question maybe there. In particular, there is a `metadata` directory with cryptic filenames which appear to be json files with information about each job. An entry of these jsons is `"incomplete": true/false`.

As an aside, it's good to know that `.snakemake/log` contains the logs of each job.

Comment: the touch a job finished file in slurm script, so i am guessing it is that: `&& touch*.jobfinished`

Comment: @curious I'm afraid I don't understand your comment. Anyway, I suspect snakemake records everything into the `.snakemake` directory. I would create a new temporary working directory, start snakemake, cancel the slurm job and while doing all this monitor the changes to the `.snakemake` directory.